# Could not find 'rspec/autorun'

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec2

I'm trying to do the first example of The rspec book

*greeter_spec.rb*

```
class RSpecGreeter
  def greet
    "Hello RSpec!"
  end
end

describe "RSpec Greeter" do
  it "should say 'Hello RSpec!' when it receives the greet() message" do
    greeter = RSpecGreeter.new
    greeting = greeter.greet
    greeting.should == "Hello RSpec!"
  end
end
```

When I run `$ rspec greeter_spec.rb` the output should be something like this:

```
.
Finished in 0.00075 seconds
1 example, 0 failures
```

but I got:

---

Could not find 'rspec/autorun'

This may happen if you're using rubygems as your package manager, but it is not
  being required through some mechanism before executing the rspec command.

You may need to do one of the following in your shell:

```
# for bash/zsh
export RUBYOPT=rubygems

# for csh, etc.
set RUBYOPT=rubygems
```

For background, please see http://gist.github.com/54177.

---

I tried to include `require 'rspec/autorun'` at the top of the file but doesn't work, also I did what they suggest on the output but still not working.

I'm using ruby version 2.0.0p648, and rspec 2.0.0